# Node callback returns mysql result but i cant print to the user with actions on google for dialogflow

Tags: mysql, node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I created an intent to get user information based on the ID he provides as param. Using a mysql module i can process the query and get the result. With a callback i can get the result to the main function but the agent ignores once i pass to a conv.ask(). What am i doing wrong?

This is my first script with node. I tried declaring pesquisar_aluno() in a variable so i could use in the main function but it retuns null.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const mysql = require('mysql')
const {
  dialogflow,
  SignIn,
  SimpleResponse
} = require('actions-on-google')


app.intent('pesquisar.alunos', (conv, params) => {

  const aluno = params.aluno
  conv.ask('Vamos pesquisar')

  pesquisar_aluno(aluno,function(result){
    var resposta = result
    console.log(resposta) // returns the result
    conv.ask(resposta) // ignores it
  })

  console.log(resposta) // returns undefined
})


function pesquisar_aluno(aluno,callback)
{
  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host : process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
  user : process.env.MYSQL_USER,
  password : process.env.MYSQL_PASS,
  database : process.env.MYSQL_DB
  })
  connection.connect()

  var query = `SELECT * FROM aluno WHERE id_aluno = "${aluno}"`

  connection.query(query, function (error, results, fields) 
  {
    if(error) throw error

    var usuario = `RA =>${results[0].id_aluno} Nome => ${results[0].nome}`
    if(callback) return callback(usuario)
  })
}
```

Expect conv.ask(resposta) to print the result to the user but its not printing anything

Edit: Changed to promises. It worked!Thanks to Nick Felker and Prisoner

```
app.intent('pesquisar.alunos', (conv, params) => {

  const aluno = params.aluno
  conv.ask('Vamos pesquisar')

  let nome = pesquisar_aluno_promise(aluno).then(function(results) {
    return results[0].nome
  }).catch((err) => setImmediate(() => { throw err; }))

  return nome.then(function(result){
    conv.ask(result) 
  })
})

async function pesquisar_aluno_promise(aluno)
{
  return new Promise(function (resolve,reject) {
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
    user : process.env.MYSQL_USER,
    password : process.env.MYSQL_PASS,
    database : process.env.MYSQL_DB
    })
    connection.connect()

    var query = `SELECT * FROM aluno WHERE id_aluno = "${aluno}"`
    connection.query(query, function (error, results, fields) 
    {
      if (error) {
        return reject(error)
      }
      resolve(results)
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: You need to use promises

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I researched about promises and implemented to the code as it shows in the edit section. It still returns the same error. Tried different ways like returning to a variable or placing the function inside a conv.ask() but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Nick suggested in the comments, you need to use Promises when you are doing asynchronous operations.

Additionally, however, you need to *return* that Promise from your Intent Handler so the Intent Dispatcher knows to wait for the result before continuing.

In your case, this can just be adding `return`, so it might look something like this:

```
  return nome.then(function(result){
    console.log(result) //works
    conv.ask(result) //should work now
  })
```